# Topic Modelling using gensim

Tags: gensim, topic-modeling

I am making SMS categorizer. For this I want to classify my messages into different topics. So I want to use gensim for that. 
Can anybody provide me the source of any tutorial that can help me to begin topic modelling using gensim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radim Řehůřek, the author of gensim, provides tutorials on his website, which I found quite helpful: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html

He also provides some tutorials on his github that are not that easy to find, so digging for a while in there might bring some great notebooks to the surface.
For example, these two (for LDA): 
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/lda_training_tips.ipynb

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_methods.ipynb

I personally found it very thrilling to start with the English Wikipedia, for which Řehůřek also provides a tutorial. Even though it takes quite a long time to train the model, you will find yourself with very "natural" seeming topics, which make it easy to test gensim's functionality.